# Replace ArrayField for several fields from other models in django-admin

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I want to store model fields as array of foreign keys to other atomic-Models. It makes model more flexible: I can add/remove/inherit(if it's tree node) any of predefined properties without programming.

Let's start with atomic-Models. It contain some classified properties.

```
class Liquid(models.Model):
    volume = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=6)

class Granular(models.Model):
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=9)

class Serial(models.Model):
    lot_number = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    estimated_release_time = models.DateTimeField()
    deadline_time = models.DateTimeField())
```

I want to emulate the following code. It's not valid because:
1. I want to store foreign keys to several models ([GenericForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) can help);
2. [ArrayField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) doesn't support array of foreign keys yet;

```
class Entity(models.Model):
        arr = ArrayField(models.ForeignKey(DifferentAtomicModels))
```

Emulation is the following. Where even numbers is pk of django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType, odd numbers is pk of atomic-Model (atomic-model obtained from the previous even number).

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    arr = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(), null=True, blank=True)
```

Well, in in django-admin changelist_view and changeform_view I want to replace arr field with fields from another models obtained from it.

What is the way to achieve this? Where it's better to intervene to django-admin behaviour (override formfield, make custom widget, smth. else...)? Now I'm looking into overriding ModelAdmin -> changeform_view, get_form, modelform_factory; but it's a lot of relations/inheritions in code, I'm a bit confused... Inlines doesn't help because there is no true foreign keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'll show my a bit dirty way to achieve this. I've overrided/created changeform_view of admin.ModelAdmin and corresponding functions/templates: get_rel_fieldsets, change_form.html maybe something else...
The code below is designed for use with categories, which can inherit some parameters from ancestors (shown as ro) and specify themselves parameters (shown as rw).

Any comments or corrections is appreciated, please note: I'm newbie in python/django.

```
# myapp/models/py
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import ArrayField
class MultiRelationalArrayField(ArrayField):
    pass

class SomeAtomicModel(models.Model):
    someproperty = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    someproperty2 = ...
    someproperty3 = ...

    def modeladmin_params(self):
        '''ModelAdmin parameters for atomicmodels can optionaly be specified in this method'''
        # Both 'fields' and 'readonly_fields' must exist!
        return {
            'fields': [('someproperty', 'someproperty2'), 'someproperty3')],
            'readonly_fields': [],
        }

class Category(MPTTModel):
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True,
        verbose_name=_("parent"), related_name='children')
    name = models.CharField(_("name"), max_length=64)
    relations = MultiRelationalArrayField(models.PositiveIntegerField(), null=True, blank=True,
        help_text=_("List of even:ContentType.id, odd:object.id. It's store relations to various predefined property sets."))

    def get_relations(self):
        relations = self.relations or []
        return relations

    def get_ancestors_relations(self):
        '''Return list of relations with relations of all ancestors starts from root'''
        relations = []
        for ct in self.get_ancestors():
            relations.extend(ct.get_relations())
        return relations

    def get_objects_from_relations(self, rel_list=None):
        '''
        Return list of objects mentioned in self.get_relations() (by default).
        If rel_list specified return list of objects from it.
        '''
        objects = []
        if rel_list is None:
            rel = self.get_relations()
            if rel == []:
                return []
            rel_list = rel
        if len(rel_list) % 2:
            # raise ValueError('List length must be even, NOT odd.')  # Doesn't work! Dont' know why
            raise RuntimeError('List length must be even, NOT odd.')
        for i in range(0, len(rel_list)-1, 2):
            objects.append(ContentType.objects.get_for_id(rel_list[i]).get_object_for_this_type(pk=rel_list[i+1]))
        return objects

    @csrf_protect_m
    @transaction.atomic
    def changeform_view(self, request, object_id=None, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        '''Customization for MultiRelationalArrayField support'''
        # Start main part of customization
        add = object_id is None
        all_rform_validated = True
        if self.rel_array_fields and not add:   # Fiedls from self.rel_array_fields will not be shown on obj addition
            to_field = request.POST.get(TO_FIELD_VAR, request.GET.get(TO_FIELD_VAR))
            # ?TODO: to_field check for rel objs
            obj = self.get_object(request, unquote(object_id), to_field)
            anc_rel = obj.get_ancestors_relations()
            rel_anc_objs = obj.get_objects_from_relations(anc_rel)
            rel_objs = obj.get_objects_from_relations()
            rel_all_objs = rel_anc_objs + rel_objs
            # rel_anc_objs will be readonly
            anc_rel_len2 = anc_rel.__len__()//2
            if request.method == 'POST' and "_saveasnew" in request.POST:
                if rel_all_objs != []:
                    return HttpResponseNotAllowed(_("'_saveasnew' option is prohibited for objects with realtions in array field."))

            # Generate ModelAdmin & ModelForm for rel_all_objs on the fly
            # rel_O_A_F = [(rel_obj instance, rel_obj_ModelAdmin instance, rel_obj_ModelForm class), ...]
            rel_O_A_F = []
            for i, o in enumerate(rel_all_objs):
                rNAME = o._meta.model.__name__ + 'RelAdmin'
                # To avoid batch ModelAdmin creations we can set ModelAdmin parameters in modeladmin_params() obj.method
                if hasattr(o, 'modeladmin_params'):
                    rparams = o.modeladmin_params()
                    rfields = rparams['fields']
                    rreadonly_fields = rparams['readonly_fields']
                else:
                    rfields = None
                    rreadonly_fields = None
                rATTRS = {
                    'formfield_overrides': self.formfield_overrides,
                    'readonly_fields': rreadonly_fields or (),
                }

                # Separation of parameters from ancestors and object parameters
                if not anc_rel_len2:  # No relations from ancestors
                    rATTRS.update({
                        'fieldsets': self.get_rel_fieldsets(request, o, False if not i else True, 1, **{'fields': rfields}),
                    })
                elif i in range(0, anc_rel_len2):  # Relations from ancestors, all will be readonly
                    rfieldsets = self.get_rel_fieldsets(request, o, False if not i else True, 0, **{'fields': rfields})
                    rATTRS.update({
                        'fieldsets': rfieldsets,
                        'readonly_fields': flatten_fieldsets(rfieldsets),
                    })
                elif i == anc_rel_len2:  # The first relation of obj (rw)
                    rfieldsets = self.get_rel_fieldsets(request, o, False, 1, **{'fields': rfields})
                    rATTRS.update({
                        'fieldsets': rfieldsets,
                    })
                else:  # Next relations of obj (rw)
                    if rfields:
                        rATTRS.update({
                            'fieldsets': [(None, {'fields': rfields})],
                        })

                rADM = type(rNAME, (admin.ModelAdmin,), rATTRS)(o._meta.model, self.admin_site)
                rel_O_A_F.append((o, rADM, rADM.get_form(request, o)))

            # Generate adminFroms for related objects
            extra_context = extra_context or {}
            extra_context['rel_anc_adminforms'] = []
            extra_context['rel_adminforms'] = []
            extra_context['media'] = []
            errlst = []
            rmedia = self.media
            for i, (robj, radm, rForm) in enumerate(rel_O_A_F):
                if request.method == 'POST':
                    rform = rForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=robj)
                    if not rform.is_valid():
                        all_rform_validated = False
                    errlst.extend(helpers.AdminErrorList(rform, []))
                else:
                    rform = rForm(instance=robj)

                radminForm = helpers.AdminForm(
                    rform,
                    list(radm.get_fieldsets(request, robj)),
                    radm.get_prepopulated_fields(request, robj),
                    radm.get_readonly_fields(request, robj),
                    model_admin=radm
                )

                if i < anc_rel_len2:
                    extra_context['rel_anc_adminforms'].append(radminForm)
                else:
                    extra_context['rel_adminforms'].append(radminForm)
                rmedia = rmedia + radminForm.media
            extra_context.update({'media': rmedia})
            if errlst:
                extra_context.update({'errors': errlst})

        # return super(ModelAdmin, self).changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context=extra_context)
        # Interrupt main part of customization. Then some inserts to official code of django 1.8 (see '# custom' at the end fo line)

        to_field = request.POST.get(TO_FIELD_VAR, request.GET.get(TO_FIELD_VAR))
        if to_field and not self.to_field_allowed(request, to_field):
            raise DisallowedModelAdminToField("The field %s cannot be referenced." % to_field)

        model = self.model
        opts = model._meta
        add = object_id is None

        if add:
            if not self.has_add_permission(request):
                raise PermissionDenied
            obj = None

        else:
            obj = self.get_object(request, unquote(object_id), to_field)

            if not self.has_change_permission(request, obj):
                raise PermissionDenied

            if obj is None:
                raise Http404(_('%(name)s object with primary key %(key)r does not exist.') % {
                    'name': force_text(opts.verbose_name), 'key': escape(object_id)})

            if request.method == 'POST' and "_saveasnew" in request.POST:
                return self.add_view(request, form_url=reverse('admin:%s_%s_add' % (
                    opts.app_label, opts.model_name),
                    current_app=self.admin_site.name))

        ModelForm = self.get_form(request, obj)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=obj)
            if form.is_valid():
                form_validated = True
                new_object = self.save_form(request, form, change=not add)
            else:
                form_validated = False
                new_object = form.instance
            formsets, inline_instances = self._create_formsets(request, new_object, change=not add)

            # if all_valid(formsets) and form_validated:  # official
            # Also check MultiRelationalArrayField models forms validation  # custom
            if all_valid(formsets) and form_validated and all_rform_validated:  # custom
                self.save_model(request, new_object, form, not add)
                self.save_related(request, form, formsets, not add)

                if add:
                    self.log_addition(request, new_object)
                    return self.response_add(request, new_object)
                else:
                    # Also save models from MultiRelationalArrayField  # custom
                    if self.rel_array_fields:  # custom
                        for robj, radm, rForm in rel_O_A_F:  # custom
                            rform = rForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=robj)  # custom
                            rnew_object = radm.save_form(request, rform, change=not add)  # custom
                            radm.save_model(request, rnew_object, rform, not add)  # custom

                    change_message = self.construct_change_message(request, form, formsets)
                    self.log_change(request, new_object, change_message)
                    return self.response_change(request, new_object)
        else:
            if add:
                initial = self.get_changeform_initial_data(request)
                form = ModelForm(initial=initial)
                formsets, inline_instances = self._create_formsets(request, self.model(), change=False)
            else:
                form = ModelForm(instance=obj)
                formsets, inline_instances = self._create_formsets(request, obj, change=True)

        adminForm = helpers.AdminForm(
            form,
            list(self.get_fieldsets(request, obj)),
            self.get_prepopulated_fields(request, obj),
            self.get_readonly_fields(request, obj),
            model_admin=self)
        media = self.media + adminForm.media

        inline_formsets = self.get_inline_formsets(request, formsets, inline_instances, obj)
        for inline_formset in inline_formsets:
            media = media + inline_formset.media

        context = dict(self.admin_site.each_context(request),
            title=(_('Add %s') if add else _('Change %s')) % force_text(opts.verbose_name),
            adminform=adminForm,
            object_id=object_id,
            original=obj,
            is_popup=(IS_POPUP_VAR in request.POST or
                      IS_POPUP_VAR in request.GET),
            to_field=to_field,
            media=media,
            inline_admin_formsets=inline_formsets,
            errors=helpers.AdminErrorList(form, formsets),
            preserved_filters=self.get_preserved_filters(request),
        )

        # Add MultiRelationalArrayField models forms errors to main form errors  # custom
        try:  # custom
            extra_context['errors'].extend(context['errors'])  # custom
        except:  # custom
            pass  # custom
        try:  # custom
            extra_context['media'] = context['media'] + extra_context['media']  # custom
        except:  # custom
            pass  # custom

        context.update(extra_context or {})
        return self.render_change_form(request, context, add=add, change=not add, obj=obj, form_url=form_url)


# myapp/admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.forms.models import fields_for_model
from django.contrib.admin.options import (csrf_protect_m, transaction, TO_FIELD_VAR, DisallowedModelAdminToField, PermissionDenied, Http404, unquote, force_text, reverse, escape, all_valid, helpers, IS_POPUP_VAR, flatten_fieldsets, partial, forms, FieldError, modelform_defines_fields, modelform_factory)
class CategoryAdmin(TreeEditor, ModelAdmin)::
    rel_array_fields = ['get_ancestors_relations', 'relations']
    readonly_rel_array_fields = ['get_ancestors_relations']
    rel_fieldsets = [
        [_('Parameters inherited from ancestors'), {
            'fields': ['get_ancestors_relations', ],
            # 'classes': ('collapse', ),
            'description': _("They also will be inherited by descendants. You can change them only via changing ancestors parameters (higher levels)."),
        }],
        [_('Parameters'), {
            'fields': ['relations', ],
            # 'classes': ('collapse', ),
            'description': _('They will be added to inherition.'),
        }],
    ]
    change_form_template = 'myapp/change_form.html'


    def get_rel_fieldsets(self, request, obj, fields_only, fieldset_index=1, **kwargs):
        if 'fields' in kwargs and kwargs['fields'] is not None:
            fields = kwargs['fields']
        else:
            fields = list(fields_for_model(obj._meta.model).keys())

        if fields_only:
            return [(None, {'fields': fields})]
        else:
            fieldset = self.rel_fieldsets[fieldset_index]
            fieldset[1]['fields'] = fields
            return [fieldset]

# myapp/templates/myapp/change_form.html
{% extends "admin/change_form.html" %}

{% block field_sets %}
{{ block.super }}
{% if rel_anc_adminforms %}
    {% for adminform in rel_anc_adminforms %}
        {% for fieldset in adminform %}
            {% if fieldset.name %}
            <fieldset class="module aligned {{ fieldset.classes }}">
                <h2>{{ fieldset.name }}</h2>
                {% if fieldset.description %}
                    <div class="description">{{ fieldset.description|safe }}</div>
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
            {% for line in fieldset %}
                {% include "biokit/includes/line.html" %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
            </fieldset>
{% endif %}
{% if rel_adminforms %}
    {% for adminform in rel_adminforms %}
        THE_SAME_AS_ABOVE
    {% endfor %}
            </fieldset>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```